# declarative_authorization and namespaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, declarative-authorization

Do you know - can declarative_authorization control access to namespace'd resources or not? I've tried something like

```
has_permission_on [:admin, :users], :to => [:index, :show, :new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy, :search]
```

but it's not working :( any ideas on this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This will work:

```
has_permission_on :admin_users, :to => [:index, :show, :new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy, :search]
```

declarative_authorization prefixes the resource name with the namespace as `[:admin, :users]` could also mean that the user has permission on the `admin_controller` and the `users_controller`.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. Why doc doesn't contain such example ^^