# declarative authorization and has_and_belongs_to_many

Tags: ruby, declarative-authorization, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a little problem with declarative-authorization. I have a User and Role Model with a has_and_belongs_to_many association.

I've created a Role named :moderator in my authorization_rules.rb

Is it possible that a User with the Role Moderator only gets the Users that have the Moderator Role assigned to it?? --> User.with_permissions_to(:index)

I thought it would be possible like that:

```
role :moderator do
  has_permission_on :users, :to => :index do
    if_attribute :roles => contains { ????? }
  end
end
```

I also created a named_scope in my User Model because I thought it would help...

```
class User
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
  named_scope :by_role, lambda { |role|
    {
      :include => :roles,
      :conditions => {"roles.name" => role}
    }
  }
end
```

Does anyone knows if it's possible to do this with declarative_authorization?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something similar in one of my projects but found dec_auth really confusing at the time. I think this is what you need to do:

authorization_rules.rb:

```
role :moderator do
  has_permission_on :users, :to => :index
end
```

User Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  using_access_control
end
```

Controller:

```
@users = User.with_permissions_to(:index)
```

Let me know if that doesn't work.

Comment: thanks for your reply! First of all I totally forgot to add "using_access_control" in my User Model... I also forgot to tell you that I'm using a admin namespace in my UsersController... I had to add a new permission to my authorization_rules called users... It's working now but -- is it possible to use namespaces in a Model?!?... I think I have to learn a bit more about this language ^^

Comment: I haven't played with namespaces yet, but I would take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079035/declarative-authorization-and-namespaces